# Stripe trial_end is null, even though it is set on the plan

Tags: stripe-payments

I am testing stripe subscriptions and updating the trial period on my existing plan to 30 days in the stripe UI.

[image]

I am creating my subscription through the API, not specifying a trial period, since I was assuming it's enough to do so in the plan.

In the response the `trial_end` is `null`. And the customer gets charged right away.

The stripe documentation mentions setting the `trial_end` it in the code:

```
(async () => {
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: 'cus_4f7dA79c5ae81a',
    items: [{plan: 'plan_CY80adF7pOi3Da2'}],
    trial_end: 1577270452,
  });
})();
```

What is the point of having the trial period set in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use the trial period from a plan you need to set the `trial_from_plan` attribute when creating the subscription.

From the Stripe documentation on [Subscription/Create](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create):

> **trial_from_plan** (optional)
>
> - Indicates if a plan’s trial_period_days should be applied to the subscription. Setting trial_end per subscription is preferred, and
>   this defaults to false. Setting this flag to true together with
>   trial_end is not allowed.